# Enable CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL after the kernel compilation

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, scheduling, real-time

I have Linux with a kernel that was compiled with the **real-time patch**, but the config option `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL` was not enabled (*it says in /proc/config that it is not set*).

Do you now if there is any way to turn this on, **without having to recompile the kernel**?

I guess it's not possible but maybe there's some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it’s a solely compile-time configuration option, there’s no runtime equivalent. You’ll need to rebuild your kernel.